# When I want the file schema.yml make with spectacular show in error assert isinstance(model_field, models.Field)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I want with using drf-spectacular to django But I get this error :

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/drf_spectacular/openapi.py", line 515, in _resolve_path_parameters     schema = self._map_model_field(model_field, direction=None)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/drf_spectacular/openapi.py", line 565, in _map_model_field     assert isinstance(model_field, models.Field) AssertionError`

`REST_FRAMEWORK = { "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema", }`

versions:

- python = "^3.11"
- django = "^5.0.0"
- pillow = "^10.1.0"
- djangorestframework = "^3.14.0"
- djangorestframework-simplejwt = "^5.3.1"
- celery = "^5.3.6"
- flower = "^2.0.1"
- mysqlclient = "^2.2.1"
- django-filter = "^23.5.0"
- pycryptodome = "^3.19.0"
- gunicorn = "^21.2.0"
- whitenoise = "6.6.0"
- django-cors-headers = "^4.3.1"

drf-spectacular = "^0.27.0"